# Find an inverse

Tags: calculus

Find $f^{-1}(2)$ if $f(x)=x^3+x$ I'm just completely stuck here. The inverse is not exactly easy to find  and I actually doubt I'm supposed to actually calculate the inverse...There is some trick that I can't find...

Comment: You just need to solve $2=x^3+x$. (No need to find the inverse in general.)

Comment: So in other words, the question could have been rephrased:

Find a number such that f(x)=2. Then the inverse of that function of 2 is that x?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the definition of the inverse function (when it exists; as it does here). $f^{-1}(2)$ is the number $x$ such that $f(x)=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Try solving $f(x) = 2$ or $x^3+x-2 = 0$.

Note that $f(0) <0$, $f(2) >0$. Try something in between...

Answer (score 1):

Since $f'(x)=3x^2 + 1 >0$, $f$ is strictly increasing, so there is at most one solution. By observation, $2 = 1 + 1 = 1^3 + 1 = f(1)$. Thus $f^{-1}(2) = \{1\}$, which is usually written $\boxed{f^{-1}(2) = 1}$ in view of the uniqueness of the solution.